# getpost content with all formatting for admin pages

Tags: plugins, filters, wp-admin, formatting, get-post

All My post usually uses various plugin based data manipulations (Like visual layout, grouping, plugin css, etc) And now I want to render a post content in my admin page. On using following code:

```
$post  = get_post(123);
$content  = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;
```

It just displaying a formated text content and I can't see my plugin based alignments, layouts which I usually can see it on normal post.

So How to get post content for admin panel all formatted along with all plugin based manipulation done?

Comment: plugins sometimes use classes and style them using external css files. Make sure you import them too.

Comment: All depends upon the plugins being used and its way of applying styles to the content on the front end. many uses hooks those are fired during the website gets rendered. Try to check if those plugins provides any filter/action after/before manipulating the content and its layout.